# How to Execute Python Custom Commands with Crontab

Tags: python, django, cron

I have a series of django custom commands that I am attempting to automate via cron-tab, through a cron.py script.

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        pass

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        #init cron
        cron = CronTab(user='dtorr')

        #add new cron job
        job = cron.new(command='python /home/dtorr/myproject/pol/sanct/management/commands/congress_dl.py >>/tmp/out.txt 2>&1')
        job1 = cron.new(command='python /home/dtorr/myproject/pol/sanct/management/commands/congress_extract.py >>/tmp/out.txt 2>&1')

        #job settings
        job.minute.every(120)
        job1.minute.every(120)
        cron.write()
```

When I check if the cron jobs have loaded using crontab -l in the terminal the commands appear, but don't appear to be executing. Do I need to reference my virtualenv in these commands somehow? What am I missing? These scripts download files, but they do not appear to be executing. I have verified that the commands work otherwise. Some of the commands appear to be working, but the following django commands fail:

The output file says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/architect/myprojectdir/sanctions/management/commands/cong_transfer.py", line 19, in <module>
    from sanct.models import Summary, Status
```

Comment: You appear to be logging the output of your `python` command execution…can you post some snippets from the logs as well?

Comment: Do those scripts need root access?

Comment: What OS are you using? Does it have a `/var/log/cron` file? Do you see any errors in `/var/log/cron`?

Comment: And yes I imaging you need to specify the full path to your virtualenv's python executable. Something like `/some/where/env/bin/python …`

Comment: So the log file output is: /bin/sh: 1: python: not found. This makes sense since python is only available in my virtualenv. How do I reference this in my commands above?

Comment: Try `/home/dtorr/env/bin/python`, but of course only you know where you put your virtual environment.

Comment: Worked! Thanks!

Comment: @RedCricket so I have an update. Some of the custom commands are, in fact, working. However, for some commands, I am getting the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/architect/myprojectdir/sanctions/management/commands/congress_transfer.py", line 19, in <module>
    from sanct.models import Summary, Status